# Internationalization / Localization in AngularJS App

Tags: angularjs, localization, internationalization, angular-translate

We have an existing angular app(Angular 1.x, AngularJS), on which we now want to apply Internationalization / Localization. I have seen many examples online. All of them suggest to create a pipe filter in angular and use the translations based on your dictionary.

This we can do, however, it is a very tedious task. 
We will have to change each and every label or text in our app.

Is there any other way we can do this? Like translating before rendering or something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can someone help?